# When creating a YAML Azure DevOps build pipeline, should the DotNetCoreCLI tasks work for .Net Framework, ,Net Core and .Net solutions?

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml, build-pipeline

When creating an Azure DevOps build pipeline, should the DotNetCoreCLI tasks work for .Net Framework, Net Core and .Net solutions?

Thanks